# get the last value of, as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there a method for getting the last value of? I want
the last number value of an amount that's incremented.
I know I've seen this method.
Thanks,

Comment: I know this stinks, but I don't know how to explain:)

Comment: can you at least give an example of the syntax? it's unclear what you're asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
var inc:Number = 450;
var total:Number = 100000000;
var target:Number = 0;

while( target < total ) {
    var n:Number = target + inc < total ? inc : total - target;
    target += n;
}
```

Comment: thanks. That's what I was looking for. I thought there was a method for this in Flash.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract 1 from the current value. That will give you the previous value of a number that has been incremented. For example:

```
var current:Number = 0;
current += 1;
var previous:Number = current - 1;
```

You could wrap this in your own custom method if you want:

```
function getPreviousValue(current:Number):Number
{
    return current - 1;
}
```